# Prevent continuous F5 on a web application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

This is related with handling the scenario when some crazy user is holding down the F5 key to send unlimited requests to our server.

Our application is very much database and cache intensive and when such consecutive requests come in; our web application is crashing after some time. I know we need to fix the application cache handling and need to add some check at the web server but I am asked to take care of this issue in our code.

I am handling this on both Javascript and server side, but looks like still it is failing, so would like to know if you have any better solution.

My code is as follows:

**Javascript Code:**

```
function checkPageRefresh(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    ar isPageRefreshed = false;

    // detect if user tries to refresh
    if ((e.keyCode == 116)            /* F5 */ ||
    (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 116)) /* Ctrl-F5 */ ||
    (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 82))  /* Ctrl-R */) {
        isPageRefreshed = true;
    }

    // only trigger special handling for page refresh
    if (isPageRefreshed){
        var lastRefreshTimeMillis= readCookie("last_refresh");
        var currentTimeMillis = new Date().getTime();

        // set cookie with now as last refresh time
        createCookie(lastRefreshCookieName, currentTimeMillis);

        var lastRefreshParsed =  parseFloat(lastRefreshTimeMillis, 10);
        var timeDiff = currentTimeMillis - lastRefreshParsed;
        var F5RefreshTimeLimitMillis = <%=request.getAttribute("F5RefreshTimeLimitMillis")%>;

        // if detected last refresh was within 1 second, abort refresh
        if (timeDiff < F5RefreshTimeLimitMillis) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        }
    } // end if (isPageRefreshed)
}
```

**Java Code:**

```
Queue<VisitsInfoHolder> recentlyVisitedUrls =  (LinkedList<VisitsInfoHolder>)session.getAttribute(SupportWebKeys.RECENTLY_VISITED_URLS);
String urlBeingCalled = PageUrlUtils.getFullURL(request);
int maxCountOfRecentURLs = 3;

if(null != recentlyVisitedUrls){
    //verify if last visit count is matching with the count provided
    if(recentlyVisitedUrls.size() >= maxCountOfRecentURLs ) {
        int noOfMatchingVisits = 0;
        Long firstAccessedTime =  0l;
        int count = 0;
        for(VisitsInfoHolder urlIno : recentlyVisitedUrls) {
            //Store the time stamp of the first record
            if(count == 0 && null != urlIno) {
                firstAccessedTime = urlIno.getTimeOfTheVisit();
            }
            count++;
            //count how many visits to the current page
            if(null != urlIno && null != urlIno.getUrl() && urlIno.getUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(urlBeingCalled)) {
                noOfMatchingVisits++;
            }
        }

        if (noOfMatchingVisits >= maxCountOfRecentURLs && (new Date().getTime() - firstAccessedTime) <= 1000){
            LOGGER.error(">>>>> Redirecting the client to the warning page.");
            VisitsInfoHolder currentVisitInfo = new VisitsInfoHolder(urlBeingCalled,new Date().getTime());
            recentlyVisitedUrls.remove();
            recentlyVisitedUrls.add(currentVisitInfo);
            response.sendRedirect((String)request.getAttribute("F5IssueRedirectPage"));
            LOGGER.error(">>>>> Redirected successfully.");
            return;
        }
        else{
            VisitsInfoHolder currentVisitInfo = new VisitsInfoHolder(urlBeingCalled,new Date().getTime());
            recentlyVisitedUrls.remove();
            recentlyVisitedUrls.add(currentVisitInfo);
            session.setAttribute(SupportWebKeys.RECENTLY_VISITED_URLS, recentlyVisitedUrls);
        }
    }
    else if (recentlyVisitedUrls.size() < maxCountOfRecentURLs) {
        VisitsInfoHolder currentVisitInfo = new VisitsInfoHolder(urlBeingCalled,new Date().getTime());
        recentlyVisitedUrls.add(currentVisitInfo);
        session.setAttribute(SupportWebKeys.RECENTLY_VISITED_URLS, recentlyVisitedUrls);
    }
}
else{
    recentlyVisitedUrls = new LinkedList<VisitsInfoHolder>();
    VisitsInfoHolder currentVisitInfo = new VisitsInfoHolder(urlBeingCalled,new Date().getTime());
    recentlyVisitedUrls.add(currentVisitInfo);
    session.setAttribute(SupportWebKeys.RECENTLY_VISITED_URLS, recentlyVisitedUrls);
}
```

Now I keep holding the F5 button then my Javascript is not understanding that the same key is held for longer time and server side code prints the following 2 loggers

- Redirecting the client to the warning page.
- Redirected successfully.

But in reality it is not redirecting any single time. I tried adding Thread.sleep(1000) before and after redirect, but still no luck.

Please let me know if you see any issue with my code or let me know if there is any better solution.

Comment: How do you know they are holding F5 rather than using some denial of service tool?  Answer: you don't. Fix your app rather than trying to cripple the user's browser, since the attacker probably isn't even using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you reproduce this problem are you the only person on your server?  Can you reproduce this problem on your local dev instance?  If so you really need to fix your server code such that it doesn't crash.  You are doing something on your server that is too intensive and needs to be optimized.

Simply intercepting the F5 key on someone's browser is treating the symptoms not the disease.  If you are having problems handling a single user hitting F5 really quickly it simply means you'll never be able to scale up to many simultaneous users because that's the exact same request/response pattern as a single user round tripping you with F5.

It's time to break out the profiler and check the timings on how long it takes to process a single request through the system.  Then look for hotspots and optimize it.  Also watch your memory usage see if you are cleaning things up or if they are growing off into infinity.